# RegQueryValueEx returns ERROR_SUCCESS but it does not get me the data buffer. Why?

Tags: c++, windows, registry

Following is the code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#define WIN_32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

void readValueFromRegistry(void)
{
  HKEY hKey;
  DWORD lRv;
  LPCWSTR subKey = L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\HRM";
  lRv = RegOpenKeyEx(
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    subKey,
    0,
    KEY_READ ,
    &hKey
  );

  if (lRv == ERROR_SUCCESS)
  {
    DWORD BufferSize = sizeof(DWORD);
    DWORD dwRet;
    DWORD cbData = 10;
    DWORD lpType;
    wchar_t cbVal[10];
    cout<<"Value before calling RegQueryValueEx is " << cbVal << endl;

    dwRet = RegQueryValueEx(
      hKey,
      L"DataBaseIn",
      NULL,
      &lpType,
      reinterpret_cast<LPBYTE>(cbVal),
      &cbData
    );
    if( lpType == REG_SZ )
        cout << "Reg_SZ" <<endl;
    if( dwRet == ERROR_SUCCESS )
      cout<<"Value is " << cbVal << endl;
    else cout<<"RegQueryValueEx failed " << dwRet << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  readValueFromRegistry();
  cin.get();
  return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
Value before calling RegQueryValueEx is 0030F810
Reg_SZ
Value is 0030F810
```

So RegQueryValueEx returns ERROR_SUCCESS, and returns the type of the value also correctly in the lpType(the `Reg_SZ`). But I dont get the value in the buffer.
It always seems to hold the garbage values.
What could be the issue and how to solve?

FYI: The key I am trying to access is created by a windows service developed by me. And DataBaseIn is the value I am trying to access:
[image: Some of the values in the HRM key]

Comment: Use `wcout` to output the text.

Comment: How did you check that the buffer contains garbage values? Note, it is not guaranteed that the returned buffer will contain terminating zero, and since you are not initializing the array - it is not safe to, simply, print the array.

Comment: `cbData` is data in in BYTES as you are using the wide version this is the wrong size. And as @mpiatek said use `wcout` as the you are asking for the unicode value.  It's useful to wrap this function (with your own version) when getting wide strings as they don't have to be zero terminated and lengths are in bytes not chars.  Also check the 64bit / 32bit subsystem see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @mpiatek after using `wcout` it is blank. It is like `Value before calling RegQueryValueEx is  `

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius after initializing the wchar_t buffer, it worked fine. Thank you!

Comment: @TobySpeight `main()` doesn't add any valid data here so did not include it in the first place. Thought to make the question direct and short enough. But what you said makes sense since people can reproduce it and run it easily if I have provided the complete code. Have edited and made it the completed code. Thanks!

Comment: Much better with the simple `main()` to make a reproducible example.  My help has to end here, though, as I don't have a Windows environment to work with.  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The char buffer should be initialized not only declared.

```
wchar_t cbVal[10] = L"";
```

Should use wcout to print unicode strings:

```
wcout << cbVal ;
```